# C++ JSON writer that allows array of strings

Tags: c++, json

I need a C++ library (or headers, or code snippet) that will allow me to write JSON that includes an array of strings, such as a bunch of error messages.

Boost's property tree does not allow arrays of strings as far as I can tell - though I am using boost for another part of the project.

Ideally the JSON can be sent to stdout, though if it has to be written to a file I can live with that.

Any ideas what I can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like http://jsoncpp.sourceforge.net/

```
Json::Value fromScratch;
Json::Value array;  // this is the array of strings
array.append("hello");
array.append("world");
fromScratch["hello"] = "world";
fromScratch["number"] = 2;
fromScratch["array"] = array;
fromScratch["object"]["hello"] = "world";

// write in a nice readible way
Json::StyledWriter styledWriter;
std::cout << styledWriter.write(fromScratch);
```

Example taken from http://www.thomaswhitton.com/blog/2013/06/27/json-c-plus-plus-examples/

Comment: Yes, JsonCpp is great!